# Converting string with nano seconds to timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Im trying to convert String Datatype to Timestamp data type but Im getting NONE as a result

Sample Data and Code

```
20181016T192403.635918+02:00

date_format = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSSSSZ”
data_frame = data_frame.withColumn('dob_ts', unix_timestamp('dob', date_format).cast(‘timestamp’)
```

Other formats (`yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS`) works fine but not this one.
How to convert this format to timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can using `udf` to define your function. Hence, in the user defined function you can handle this case by an `if` or what you want:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf 
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

def date_time_to_date(input_date_time):
     split_ind = input_date_time.find('T')
     new_date = input_date_time
     if split_ind > -1:
         new_date = input_date_time[:split_ind] + input_date_time[split_ind + 1:]
     return datetime.strptime(input_date_time, '%Y%m%d %H%M%S.%f')

udf_date_time_to_date = udf(new_date, TimestampType())

data_frame = data_frame.withColumn('dob_ts', udf_date_time_to_date('dob'))
```